# How can I understand something from hashicorp vault audit?

Tags: security, hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to get familiar with Hashicorp Vault and I don't understand how to use its audit log?

For example, let's say, one of the admins was compromised and somebody with root-token created another one root-token. I'm getting an audit log like this:

```
{
  "time": "2019-08-17T21:53:07.625384189Z",
  "type": "request",
  "auth": {
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:0c97855631748ce0a775e3efc79fc607b0d2f61ddeb78b15e915a5087013fb5b",
    "accessor": "hmac-sha256:c081cc37603419f02e67fb93f2f1362aa0eb37fa42635606cc51b9b7ed1ed561",
    "display_name": "root",
    "policies": [
      "root"
    ],
    "token_policies": [
      "root"
    ],
    "token_type": "service"
  },
  "request": {
    "id": "f8b0f707-7e38-1410-4173-235ff9e250b6",
    "operation": "update",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:0c97855631748ce0a775e3efc79fc607b0d2f61ddeb78b15e915a5087013fb5b",
    "client_token_accessor": "hmac-sha256:c081cc37603419f02e67fb93f2f1362aa0eb37fa42635606cc51b9b7ed1ed561",
    "namespace": {
      "id": "root"
    },
    "path": "auth/token/create",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "hmac-sha256:0f235cb7061e26e25b346c787a036860e247e0e32181b8adf13850812a27a9f1",
      "entity_alias": "hmac-sha256:0f235cb7061e26e25b346c787a036860e247e0e32181b8adf13850812a27a9f1",
      "explicit_max_ttl": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "num_uses": "hmac-sha256:943213e389eae841e8d03f94149bc8e564973fd4c6f0eabe76061dd4355b03b0",
      "period": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "renewable": true,
      "ttl": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "type": "hmac-sha256:792572c378bcb0b0400ad2033078e80334dfd06d76d948866960ad9b8547ba62"
    },
    "remote_address": "127.0.0.1"
  }
}
{
  "time": "2019-08-17T21:53:07.709275872Z",
  "type": "response",
  "auth": {
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:0c97855631748ce0a775e3efc79fc607b0d2f61ddeb78b15e915a5087013fb5b",
    "accessor": "hmac-sha256:c081cc37603419f02e67fb93f2f1362aa0eb37fa42635606cc51b9b7ed1ed561",
    "display_name": "root",
    "policies": [
      "root"
    ],
    "token_policies": [
      "root"
    ],
    "token_type": "service"
  },
  "request": {
    "id": "f8b0f707-7e38-1410-4173-235ff9e250b6",
    "operation": "update",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:0c97855631748ce0a775e3efc79fc607b0d2f61ddeb78b15e915a5087013fb5b",
    "client_token_accessor": "hmac-sha256:c081cc37603419f02e67fb93f2f1362aa0eb37fa42635606cc51b9b7ed1ed561",
    "namespace": {
      "id": "root"
    },
    "path": "auth/token/create",
    "data": {
      "display_name": "hmac-sha256:0f235cb7061e26e25b346c787a036860e247e0e32181b8adf13850812a27a9f1",
      "entity_alias": "hmac-sha256:0f235cb7061e26e25b346c787a036860e247e0e32181b8adf13850812a27a9f1",
      "explicit_max_ttl": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "num_uses": "hmac-sha256:943213e389eae841e8d03f94149bc8e564973fd4c6f0eabe76061dd4355b03b0",
      "period": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "renewable": true,
      "ttl": "hmac-sha256:3cf83aa363c8f73a7e23ccd56baa8f4e1119bc15800030f663f2d07c5420ce91",
      "type": "hmac-sha256:792572c378bcb0b0400ad2033078e80334dfd06d76d948866960ad9b8547ba62"
    },
    "remote_address": "127.0.0.1"
  },
  "response": {
    "auth": {
      "client_token": "hmac-sha256:fdb305fbabaf0044fc6d696fb2d0ff3d96574ff4d7fab804e8d5d36b7f2ddd14",
      "accessor": "hmac-sha256:19f3a70ceea337f067c053249504fbf8e8c164304b66a8c97fad421d43b5e4af",
      "display_name": "token",
      "policies": [
        "root"
      ],
      "token_policies": [
        "root"
      ],
      "token_type": "service"
    }
  }
}
```

How can I find out who it was? 
How can I get the accessor of the token that was compromised? 
Where can I get an accessor of the just created token to revoke it?

Or maybe I didn't get purposes of the Vault audit right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a cool option that hepled me: `hmac_accessor = false`, here is the audit log with tis option enabled:

```
{
  "time": "2019-08-27T07:55:57.888464574Z",
  "type": "response",
  "auth": {
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:84c8887e815c04aeef145ebffa05f9ef6fde166d7645b5046416d76add283fef",
    "accessor": "y1lRcyzxkPgL0gmQ45WqliPy",
    "display_name": "root",
    ...
  },
  "request": {
    "id": "f4dc76af-b562-ae2c-8d6f-dd6a0d6f7ef6",
    "operation": "update",
    "client_token": "hmac-sha256:84c8887e815c04aeef145ebffa05f9ef6fde166d7645b5046416d76add283fef",
    "client_token_accessor": "y1lRcyzxkPgL0gmQ45WqliPy",
    ...
  },
  "response": {
    ...
  },
  "error": ""
}
```

**UPD:** list of current accessors:

```
$ vault list auth/token/accessors                                                
Keys
----
MelMLthx4K4FznCbNIB8xbC6
bOnatDe7MXfdB9f3CRuGPo0h
y1lRcyzxkPgL0gmQ45WqliPy
VerAvaBln92HG38gKbKEcXOZ
```

Get info about token by the accessor:

```
$ vault write auth/token/lookup-accessor accessor=VerAvaBln92HG38gKbKEcXOZ
Key                 Value
---                 -----
accessor            VerAvaBln92HG38gKbKEcXOZ
creation_time       1566893336
creation_ttl        3m
display_name        token
entity_id           n/a
expire_time         2019-08-27T11:11:56.903211142+03:00
explicit_max_ttl    0s
id                  n/a
issue_time          2019-08-27T11:08:56.903210949+03:00
meta                <nil>
num_uses            0
orphan              false
path                auth/token/create
period              3m
policies            [root]
renewable           true
ttl                 2m55s
type                service
```